# Dynamically compare accuracy of regex patterns for match

Tags: javascript, regex

Supposing I have two regexes and both match a string, but one of them matches it in a stricter way, is there a way to figure that out programmatically?

For example, I'm matching this string:

```
/path/on/file/system
```

and I have the following two regular expressions:

```
const opt1 = /\/path\/on/;
const opt2 = /\/path/;
```

I can see with my eyes that `opt1` is stricter, but how can javascript know about that?

Is converting the regex to a string and checking for character length a good measure of strictness?

Comment: It isn't *"stricter"*. It is matching `/on/` in the string where as the first one isn't so the only difference is `opt1` is more specific to match `/path/on/` where as `opt2` will match anything that contains `/path/`

Comment: @NewToJS Yes, that is what I mean. Do you know the answer?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *"how can javascript know"* It knows because it returns a true or false if a match it found not a percentage of how much could be matched. Maybe you are looking for a comparison to return a **%** of a match?

Comment: `but how can javascript know about that?` it doesn't, you only use one RegExp at a time, both will match, javascript doesn't care, you care.

Comment: `s.match(opt1)[0].length > s.match(opt2)[0].length` does that help?

Comment: What is requirement?

Comment: or, using `const opt1 = /(\/path)(\/on)/, opt2 = /(\/path)/;` ... then `s.match(opt1).length > s.match(opt2).length`

Comment: There is definitely no simple general solution to this, or even a clear definition for what "strictness" in regex means. I guess you could define it as "total number of possible matches" but when wildcards and character sets are involved, that becomes hard to measure, and it is not uncommon for regex patterns to have infinite potential matches. Maybe a good-enough approach would be to count the number of literal characters in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this function by:

Sorting your regular expressions by length.

loop through your sorted regular expressions array to check if there is a match

then return the most strict matching element.

```js
function check(arrayOfRegEx, str) {
    //sort the regex array by length 
   var sortedArr = arrayOfRegEx.sort(function(a, b) { 
    return a.toString().length - b.toString().length || a.toString().localeCompare(b);
   });
  
   let mostStrict = '';
   sortedArr.forEach(function(reg) {
     if(new RegExp((reg.toString()).replace(/\\/g, "").substring(1)).test(str)) {
 mostStrict = reg;
      }
   });

   return mostStrict;
}

var result = check([/\/path/, /\/test\/test/, /\/path\/on/], '/path/on/file/system'); 

console.log(result); // returns /\/path\/on/
```

And of course you can tweak this function to fit your needs